# rows of divs overlay.... example: outer div is entire page... within that, there are "n" rows of divs, with 2 columns each...

Tags: html, image, divider

trying to get a multi-row div to appear within an outer div... first "row" works fine, 2nd overlays ...

I made 2 images, one, test.png is a green background image, 400 (w) x 840 (h) ... 2nd is red background, 360 (w) x 756 (h)... it doesn't appear I can upload them? I did the 2nd in red so I  could  tell if it was overlaying... it is overlaying the first column... 
  I can't find relevant text/instructions to tell me how to do this... the divs left_promo and right_promo are the "rows"... when I invoke the left_promo for the 2nd "row", it overlays the first row, left column, and does not start on a new "row" boundary... 
  if you need the images, I can include them if someone tells me how... it seems I can't...

```
  1) HTML code

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\GNO\css\newmain.css" />
<p>some text</p>
<div style="padding: 0 8px; height: 1100px; width: 1150px; overflow: auto;"> 
<div class="left_promo">
 <img src="C:\GNO\images\test.png">
</div>

 <div class="right_promo">

 <img src="C:\GNO\images\test.png">

  </div>

 <div class="left_promo">
 <img src="C:\GNO\images\red.png">
</div>  

  </div>
<!-- <div style="padding: 0 8px; height: 800px; width: 1150px; overflow: auto;"> 
 -->
<!--    </div>
 -->
</html>

  2) CSS code  
    @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
/* padding is top, right, bottom, left  */ 

div.left {
    background:#F7E2F1;
    height:1650px;
    width:200px;
    position:absolute;
    margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
div.left_promo {
    height:450px;
    width:565px;
   position:absolute;
     margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
div.right_promo {
    height:450px;
    width:565px;
   position:absolute; 
    margin:10px 10px 10px 620px;
}

div.right{
    background:#F7E2F1;
    height:1650px;
    width:650px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    margin:10px 440px 10px 10px;   /* the right offset margin pushes the content left   */
}

.container{
    background:#F7E2F1;
    height:1650px;  
    width:1550px;
    position:relative;
    margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.bottom{
    background:purple;
    height:150px;
    width:980px;
    margin:140px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn`t understand the problem quite well. But strongly believe this what you wanted.

Here is the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/tyy6p621/. You only need to properly close and open some tags

```
    <div style="padding: 0 8px; height: 1100px; width: 1150px; overflow: auto;"> 
       <div class="left_promo">
              <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-5WVRHaM3hGo/UrT2eNS11GI/AAAAAAAAUZo/W3YcLkt10z0/s1600/s4-mini-la-fleur-.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="right_promo">
             <img src="https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/54304027/disp/b01a81ad9fac3f60ab871f18d8db2db9.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="padding: 0 8px; height: 1100px; width: 1150px; overflow: auto;"> 
        <div class="left_promo">
            <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-5WVRHaM3hGo/UrT2eNS11GI/AAAAAAAAUZo/W3YcLkt10z0/s1600/s4-mini-la-fleur-.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="right_promo">
            <img src="https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/54304027/disp/b01a81ad9fac3f60ab871f18d8db2db9.jpg">
        </div>

    </div>
```